# Create a Complex Join/Create VIEW

Tags: sql, join, view

I am needing to create a Complex JOIN query that uses 3 tables show match a predefined Order Form. The form shows certain data from 2 of the tables and All of the data from the 3rd table. In any case, in my attempt at failing I thought it would be possible to do the same thing by Creating a table view that combines the data I Need. No matter what I try I get a syntax error using phpMyAdmin.

The latest code I tried was the following with unknonw syntax error.

```
CREATE VIEW SAlES_ORDER
FROM customer_info, item_info, order_info
WHERE customer_info.CustomerID=1
AND order_info.OrderID=1
```

I need the information from customer 1 and orderID 1 joined together with ALL data info from the Item table. I am not understanding how to create this or View it for that matter which is why I tried the CREATE VIEW route. I feel I am missing something simple here and this is the Final step of my project to submit this.

Comment: what is your target data base?  Oracle? Sql server? DB2? Access (Ha! i crack me up!)

Comment: basic SQL. We were advised to use SQLFiddle but it wasnt working at the time I began my project so I used XAMP installer to setup phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some parts of the syntax. Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW SAlES_ORDER AS
SELECT * 
FROM customer_info, item_info, order_info
WHERE customer_info.CustomerID=1
AND order_info.OrderID=1
```

But unless you really want a cross join, you probably want proper joins with conditions:

```
CREATE VIEW SAlES_ORDER AS
SELECT * 
FROM customer_info
JOIN order_info ON order_info.CustomerID = customer_info.CustomerID
JOIN item_info ON item_info.OrderID = order_info.OrderID
```

And leave the WHERE clause off but specify it when you use it.

Comment: I think your correct in using the Join route since my rubric specifies "Join Query". I will give that a try and I dont think I need to use the Where clause for this. Also, I didnt consider using VIEW with JOIN or is that the only way I would actually see the end result? i have tried queries before that resulted in "Success" but didnt visually Show any result.